# I need a formula to check that dates are sequential in rows

Tags: excel, date, formula

I have 6 columns of dates, and I need to make sure that the dates ascend in value as you move from left to right.

This is what I have so far, but it returns TRUE when it shouldn't.

`=IF(K22>=J22>=I22>=H22>=G22>=F22,TRUE,FALSE)`

Comment: use AND, as in `AND(K22>=J22,J22>=I22,I22>=H22,H22>=G22,G22>=F22)`

Comment: @nutsch That's closer, I have empty cells that seem to be messing it up still

Comment: you can change each portion with an `OR`, e.g. K22>=J22 becomes `OR(K22>=J22,J22="",K22="")`

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with a formula that is under each cell, you can get this by comparing the current value to the `MAX` of the previous values.  You can then add a final cell at the end to summarize and give the single answer.

**Picture of ranges and result**

[image: picture of ranges]

**Formulas** in cell `C3` is a normal formula copied to the right under the numbers.  This formula uses a mixed absolute/relative reference to get the `cells to the left of the current one`.  `I3` is the summary cell which is just an `AND` on the rest of the cells.

```
[C3] = IF(ISBLANK(C2),TRUE,C2>MAX($B$2:B2))
[I3] = AND(C3:G3)
```

As it sits, this one allows for a blank to not affect the result.  `MAX` ignores the blank and the formula returns a `TRUE` for it so as to not affect the summary cell.

Here is the same result in the failing case:

[image: picture with FALSE]

The one upside to the per-cell formula is that it could easily be used for conditional formatting so that it is apparent which cells are out of order.